# Data model is not updated when submitting form with RichFaces tabpanel

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I have the following layout in my page (simplified)

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton action="#{bean.save} value="Save"/>

    <rich:tabPanel switchType="ajax">
        <rich:tab name="one" switchType="client">

        </rich:tab>

        <rich:tab name="two" switchType="ajax">

        </rich:tab>

        <rich:tab name="three" switchType="client">

        </rich:tab>

    </rich:tabPanel>
</h:form>
```

Tabs "one" and "three" have switchType="client", there are some inputs on them, bound to a bean properties. When "Save" is pressed, I expect that bean properties will updated from input in both tabs. However, the properties are updated only from the inputs on the current tab. Values from another tab are lost, though the whole form is submitted (I have checked it in HTTP watcher). So the user has to input data in one tab, press "Save", then update values on another tab and press "Save" in order to save all changes made. How it is possible to propagate values from all tabs at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution has been found: I have changed switchType of the tabpanel from "ajax" to "client". Thanks all for your proposals!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly easily with javascript. All you need to do (once your tabs are set) is to add the logic to show and hide the different tabbed components.

Comment: The problem is not in showing or hiding tabbed components. The problem is that values from hidden tabs are not propagating to the data model, though they are submitted via HTTP

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was to put all of your form elements onto one form and hide the different sections of it with javascript. It seems that maybe each tab is functioning as its own form?

Comment: That's not an option, we have a bunch of pages implemented using tab panel, and I would like to get things right with this approach.

Comment: when the page is rendered, does each tab contain its own form?

Comment: No, the all tabs are in one form, as specified in the markup above

Comment: I just wasnt sure if that markup was rendering as intended. It seems like it is only posting the data back from the selected tab as if it is in its own form.

Comment: The data is posted correctly - all values are submitted via HTTP. I suppose the problem is somewhere on the server side, when tab panel is going through JSF lifecycle

Comment: except not all of it is being posted back to the server. What I was curious about is if when your page is rendered, it treats the elements on each tab as its own form (you would be able to tell by looking at the generated html).  For whatever reason it is not sending all of the data back, the data is lazily loaded and not present when the form is submitted, or it is treating each tab as its own page (in which case the data wouldnt be there).

Comment: The solution has been found: I have changed switchType of the tabpanel from "ajax" to "client"

Answer (score 0):

First, change the `<h:commandButton />` to `<a4j:commandButton />` so your submit will be made by ajax requests to the server. Also, you can rerender the content of the page after the operation.

```html
<h:form>
    <!-- RichFaces 3.3 -->
    <a4j:commandButton value="Save"
        action="#{bean.save}"
        reRender="tbpMyTabs" />
    <!-- RichFaces 4. -->
    <a4j:commandButton value="Save"
        action="#{bean.save}"
        render=":tbpMyTabs" />

    <rich:tabPanel id="tbpMyTabs" switchType="ajax">
        <rich:tab name="one" switchType="client">
        </rich:tab>
        <rich:tab name="two" switchType="ajax">
        </rich:tab>
        <rich:tab name="three" switchType="client">
        </rich:tab>
    </rich:tabPanel>
</h:form>
```

To make a successful action ajax request, change the `Save` method to return a void, so JSF won't follow a navigation rule. If you're working with JSF 2, your bean should have view scope, else it should have request scope and the `KeepAlive` annotation.

RichFaces 3.3 Bean implementation

```
@KeepAlive
public class Bean {
    public Bean() {
    }
    public void save() {
    }
}
```

JSF 2 / RichFaces 4.x Bean implementation

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {
    public Bean() {
    }
    public void save() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work either. And how changing <h:commandButton> to <a4j:commandButton> could help?

Comment: If you're using different beans inside each `<rich:tab>`, they should have the `@KeepAlive` tag and request scope (RF 3.x) or view scope (JSF 2/RF 4). Maybe if you post a sample of what you're doing I can edit my post to give an accurate answer, instead of guessing what could you have.

Comment: The solution has been found: I have changed switchType of the tabpanel from "ajax" to "client"